# Laravel Collection::toArray() triggers extra database queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Let's use the typical posts/tags example. And let's say I want to pull some posts' details. I'm a smart developer who wants to limit database queries, so I eager load the relationship to the tags.

```
<?php
class Post extends Model {
    public function tags() { return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class); }
}

class Tag extends Model {
    public function posts() { return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class); }
}

$posts = Post::query()->with("tags")->where("title", "like", "foo%")->get();
```

So far, so good. My database's query log shows two queries:

```
select * from `posts` where `title` like 'foo%' and `posts`.`deleted_at` is null;
select `tags`.*, `post_tag`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id`, `post_tag`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id`
    from `tags` inner join `post_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `post_tag`.`tag_id`
    where `post_tag`.`post_id` in (19, 880, 1462, 2712, 2713, 2717);
```

I can now work with the posts and tags without issue. For example, I can run this code without any further database queries:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->title . "(" . implode(",", $post->tags->pluck("name")->all()) . ")";
}
```

This tells me that the data from the relationship has been saved into the collection `$posts`, as expected.

---

So, my question is: why does calling `$posts->toArray()` or `$posts->toJson()` result in *another* query to my pivot table for **every item** in the collection, pulling the same data that is already stored in the collection?

```
select `tags`.*, `post_tag`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id`, `post_tag`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id`
from `tags` inner join `post_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `post_tag`.`tag_id`
where `post_tag`.`post_id` = 19 limit 1;
select `tags`.*, `post_tag`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id`, `post_tag`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id`
from `tags` inner join `post_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `post_tag`.`tag_id`
where `post_tag`.`post_id` = 880 limit 1;
...
select `tags`.*, `post_tag`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id`, `post_tag`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id`
from `tags` inner join `post_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `post_tag`.`tag_id`
where `post_tag`.`post_id` = 2717 limit 1;
```

Is there some way I can keep these extra queries from happening?

Comment: are you 'appending' data to the models with the `appends` property? doing anything with accessors?

Comment: can you show the rest of the Post model

Comment: On my Pc it cause 3 query if never done before, one with limit 1, one select *, and then the pivot query

Comment: You called it @lagbox. There is an append on the "Posts" model that pulls an accessor to return the first "tag". Rewriting it to return `$this->tags->first()` instead of `$this->tags()->first()` fixed things up.

Comment: ah, glad you found it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an accessor that is being 'appended' to the model data via the `$appends` property. It is probably hitting the relationship method and causing a query instead of using the dynamic property for the relationship.